# Can't use the drag function in .h when using storyboard with more than one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't use the control drag function to hook up a button to action in .h when using storyboard with more than one view controller
Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you've assigned the view controller a custom class? and dragging to that specific class? Each view controller should have its own Obj-c class. To create one:

press cmd + n and create a new Objective-C class and make it a subclass of UITableViewController (or the view controller you used in your Storyboard). after doing so, go to you Storyboard and select the view controller, on the right menu choose "Identity Inspector" and set the custom class name to the name of the class you just created.

Comment: Objective-C Class, as I've written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **class file name** for the `UIViewController` of the storyboard file at the identity inspector .

[image]

Comment: How can I add a new class?